# Lambda not assuming role in AWS serverless framework from Cognito User Pool. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, serverless, role-based-access-control

I'm trying to create a admin API using api gateway, lambda and dynamoDB. I want only the logged in users in certain group be able to access lambda.

I see that the lambda would not assume role of the cognito user  and access the dynamoDB. API only works if I attach the dynamoDB policy to the LambdaRole.

Is there a way for this to work dynamically based on user groups. Do I need to add this assumeRole logic in the lambda handler itself ? Please help

This is the **ERROR** I get when I git my API from postman with Authorization tokens

```
{
  "message": "User: arn:aws:sts::09723XXXXX357:assumed-role/tango-admin-lambda-role/tango-admin-service-dev-getActiveOrders is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:Query on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:09723XXXXX357:table/dev-tango-service-tango-order-db",
  "code": "AccessDeniedException",
  "time": "2022-05-23T18:42:39.241Z",
  "requestId": "DDK7AS6SBO8D0U3KXXXXXXXX",
  "statusCode": 400,
  "retryable": false,
  "retryDelay": 46.2351059972586
}
```

Here is my serverless.yml file

```
service: tango-admin-service

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs14.x
  region: us-east-1
  environment:
    DYNAMODB_TABLE: ${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}-tango-service-tango-order-db
# functions
functions:
  hello:
    handler: src/handlers/hello.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: hello
          method: get

  getActiveOrders:
    handler: src/handlers/getActiveOrders.handler
    role: TangoAdminLambdaRole # How can this role be assume from Congito ? It only works if I directly pass the Role with DynamoDB Policy
    events: # The events that trigger this function
      - http:
          path: get-active-orders
          method: post
          cors: true
          authorizer:
            type: COGNITO_USER_POOLS
            authorizerId:
              Ref: TangoAdminApiAuthorizer

# Serverless plugins
plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-typescript
  - serverless-offline

resources:
  Resources:
    
    TangoAdminCognitoUserPool:
      Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
      Properties:
        UserPoolName: TangoAdmin
        
    TangoAdminCognitoUserPoolClient:
      Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient
      Properties:
        ClientName: TangoAdminWebApp
        GenerateSecret: false
        UserPoolId:
          Ref: "TangoAdminCognitoUserPool"
          
    TangoAdminGroup:
      Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolGroup
      Properties:
        GroupName: "TangoAdmin"
        Description: "Admin group for Tango"
        Precedence: 0
        RoleArn: !GetAtt CognitoAdminIAMRole.Arn
        UserPoolId:
          Ref: "TangoAdminCognitoUserPool"
          
    CognitoAdminIAMRole:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
      Properties:
        RoleName: "tango-admin-role"
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                Federated:
                  - "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
              Action:
                - "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"
        Policies:
          - PolicyName: "tango-admin-group-policy"
            PolicyDocument:
              Version: "2012-10-17"
              Statement:
                - Effect: Allow
                  Action:
                    - "dynamodb:*"
                  Resource:
                    - "arn:aws:dynamodb:${opt:region, self:provider.region}:*:table/${self:provider.environment.DYNAMODB_TABLE}"

    TangoAdminApiAuthorizer:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer
      Properties:
        Name: TangoAdmin
        RestApiId:
          Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
        Type: COGNITO_USER_POOLS
        ProviderARNs:
          - Fn::GetAtt: [ TangoAdminCognitoUserPool, Arn ]
        IdentitySource: method.request.header.Authorization
    
    TangoAdminLambdaRole:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
      Properties:
        RoleName: "tango-admin-lambda-role"
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
              Action:
                - "sts:AssumeRole"
  Outputs:
    TangoAdminCognitoUserPoolId:
      Description: "Tango Admin Cognito User Pool ID"
      Value:
        Ref: "TangoAdminCognitoUserPool"
    TangoAdminCognitoUserPoolClientId:
      Description: "Tango Admin Cognito User Pool Client ID"
      Value:
        Ref: "TangoAdminCognitoUserPoolClient"
```